# C# Regex: Get group names?

Tags: c#, regex

```
myRegex.GetGroupNames()
```

Seems to return the numbered groups as well... how do I get only the named ones?

A solution using the actual Match object would be fine as well.

Comment: Why do you have both named and numbered groups? Why not just stick to one or the other? Can you post your regular expression?

Comment: @Mark: I don't. They're added automatically (the group can be referend by name or number). My regex is `^(?:/image:(?<id>\d+))$`. The outer parentheses should be non-capturing if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: **Edit:** Actually, the 0 is probably the one matching the entire regex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public string[] GetGroupNames(Regex re)
{
    var groupNames = re.GetGroupNames();
    var groupNumbers = re.GetGroupNumbers();

    Contract.Assert(groupNames.Length == groupNumbers.Length);

    return Enumerable.Range(0, groupNames.Length)
        .Where(i => groupNames[i] != groupNumbers[i].ToString())
        .Select(i => groupNames[i])
        .ToArray();
}
```

Actually, this will still fail when the group name and number happen to be the same :\ *But* it will succeed even when the group name is a number, as long as the number is not the same as its index.

Comment: Yes...read the last paragraph. It still fails under that one condition. If you know a way around this, please enlighten me :) **Edit:** Doh...you deleted your comment. Now this looks out of place.

Answer (score 7):

Does using the `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` option when creating the regex do what you want ? e.g.

```
Regex theRegex = new Regex(@"\b(?<word>\w+)\b", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx):

> Specifies that the only valid captures
>   are explicitly named or numbered
>   groups of the form `(?<name>...)`. This
>   allows unnamed parentheses to act as
>   noncapturing groups without the
>   syntactic clumsiness of the expression
>   `(?:...)`.

So you won't need to worry about whether users of your API may or may not use non-capturing groups if this option is set.

Comment: Oh! Sneaky. I have to think about this. I wanted to handle named and numbered captures separately which is why it is important for me to differentiate between the two... but I'm debating how useful the support of numbered captures is. **Edit:** Even with explicit capture, it still returns the 0th capture, but that can be easily trimmed off.

Comment: Named groups and numbered groups shouldn't be used in the same regex anyway; it's just too confusing.  If you don't control the source of the regexes, you can save yourself a lot of hassle by forcing ExplicitCapture mode.  Additionally, you might want to forbid the use of group names that *look* like numbers, e.g. `(?<2>...)`

Comment: @Alan: Perhaps they shouldn't be mixed, but I think they should still have the choice of either. This is going into a url-router for a web framework. The named matches will become arguments to a function with parameters by the same name. Alternatively, they can use numbered matches to fill the arguments left to right.

Comment: @Ralph Run a transformation over it and prevent direct regex use? :-) E.g the "input" may look like "foo/{id:\d+}"

Comment: @pst: Well that's no fun... I don't want to teach them something new just because I'm having some technological issue. Burden should be on me, not the user. Anyway, I'm just going to disallow number-names and all should be good.

Comment: Of course you still get a group named `0`, which I find to be very sneaky and rather undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

See the other comments/answers about using `(?:)` and/or sticking with "one style". Here is my best approach that tries to directly solve the question:

```
var named = regex.GetGroupNames().Where(x => !Regex.IsMatch(x, "^\\d+$"));
```

However, this will fail for regular expressions like `(?<42>...)`.

Happy coding.

Comment: Yes... I think we can do one better though. Coding it up now.

Comment: @Ralph Consider this case: `(?<1>..)` -- GetGroupNumbers/Names should still "line up" :-)

Comment: Yeah :( But it's still slightly more robust than this solution :P